# Pygame, two windows one releated to other (Menu-like)

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I am wondering if it is possible to create two windows in two different .py files where the first window will be some settings about the game, and the second the game with the setting, set by the user in the first window.

The first screen, it would be something easy, like 3 texts where the user can choose with the arrows. And when one of the three texts pressed, the game will be load on the screen.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to create a window where a user can choose the resolution, or other settings, with a play button.

I would recommend Tkinter for the job.
[Here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-index.htm) you will find some tutorials about it.

You should then link a button with launching of the game itself.

EDIT:

Since you want to use pygame, this is still possible. Just have 2 seperate pygame scripts, and launch the second script after a MOUSE_DOWN event on one of the texts.

Comment: Thank you but I prefer to use pygame instant of tkinder.

Answer (score 0):

If by two windows you mean two *separate* windows, then no, PyGame can't do that *yet*.

This feature was only just added in SDL2, and I hardly think PyGame is using SDL2 yet.

If you want to use SDL2 with Python, then have a look at PySDL2: http://pysdl2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/pygamers.html

It is suggested that you can fake it using multiprocessing: [Creating multiple screens in pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376479/creating-multiple-screens-in-pygame)

---

If you want two different *applications* (a launcher and the game), then that shouldn't be much trouble. Just treat them as two separate PyGame applications.