# How do I make a new window in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

My current code is below, what I want to happen is after the button has been clicked I would like it to go to a blank page with 'Hello' printed in the middle of it. The code is below:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.4
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
windowHeight = 600
windowWidth = 900

def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((windowWidth, windowHeight))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Test')
    background = pygame.image.load('background.jpg')
    screen.blit(background, (0,0))
    face = pygame.image.load('text.gif')
    b = screen.blit(face, (300, 300))

    while 1:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
                x, y = event.pos
                if b.collidepoint(x, y):
                    face = pygame.image.load('background.jpg')
                    b = screen.blit(face, (300, 300))
                else: 
                    face = face = pygame.image.load('text.gif')
                    b = screen.blit(face, (300, 300))
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
                x, y = event.pos
                if b.collidepoint(x, y):
                    print("button has been clicked")

        pygame.display.update()

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    main()
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do here, your `while` loop would run before `main()`, and cause NameError-s because you don't have screen defined yet. If you want to just make a screen, you have the right idea, just include the `while` loop in `main`. If you want to make several screens, you can't in pygame [Source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376479/creating-multiple-screens-in-pygame)

Answer (score 2):

You can create new class for example HelloWorld with label: "Hello world" and create function where you lauching class HelloWorld.
For example(Python 2.7):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    def _creator():        
        screen2 = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT),0,32)
        hello = HelloWorld(screen2)
        hello.run()
    MENU_ITEMS = ("Welcome", "Exit")
    SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600), 0, 32)
    FUNCS = {"Welcome": _creator, "Exit": sys.exit}
    GM = Main(SCREEN, FUNCS.keys(), FUNCS)
    GM.run()
```

When you click "Welcome" you launch class HelloWorld.

Answer (score 0):

After your original code, write a new function for new window in the same way you wrote for your main window, then bind that funtion with that button in main window.